# Design pattern for observing changes in array field within an object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to know what is the best design pattern if i want to observe changes 
in a field of a document which contains an array of object. I know that 
meteor observeChanges only gives changes in the direct fields.

I have a document like:

```
Post: {
  title: "dfsfdsf",
  comments: [ {
     text: "213434"
   }, ... 
  ]
}
```

I want to observeChanges in comment field. What is the best way to do it? 
Do I have to use observe and compare old and new document ?

Comment: Hi, just a few questions so I can give a direct answer. 1. Is this server or client, 2. What changes do you need, eg. changes to `text` field, or just if a comment was added / removed? 3. do you need to monitor a single post or multiple posts at the same time?